# jQuery - Create public method that uses configured options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, public-method

I'm trying to create a basic plugin that uses options and then a method off the object that uses the set options.

```
 $.sn_Watermark = $.sn_Watermark || {
        options: {
            waterMarkText: "Watermark Text",
            className: "watermarked"
        },
        show: function(selector) {
            $(selector)
                .addClass("watermarked")
                .val("Watermark Text");
        }
    };  

   $.fn.sn_Watermark = $.fn.sn_Watermark || function (options) {
            if(options == null)
                options = $.sn_Watermark.options;
            else
                options = $.extend($.sn_Watermark.options, options);

            return this.each(function () {
                $tb = $(this);
                    if ($tb.val() == "" || $tb.val() == options.waterMarkText ) {
                        $tb.addClass(options.className);
                        $tb.val(options.waterMarkText);
                    }
                }).focus(function () {
                    $tb = $(this);
                    if ($tb.val() == options.waterMarkText) {
                        $tb.val("");
                        $tb.removeClass(options.className);
                    }
                }).blur(function () {
                //var clearLnk = "[LnkClearRowNum=" + $tb.attr('TextBoxRowNum') + "]";
                if ($tb.val() == '') {
                    // $(clearLnk).hide();
                    $tb.addClass(options.className);
                    $tb.val(options.waterMarkText);
                }
                else if ($tb.val() == options.waterMarkText){ //if user types in water mark text
                    $tb.addClass(options.className);
                }
                else {
                    //$(clearLnk).show();
                    $tb.removeClass(options.className);
                }
            });
        };

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("[TextBoxRowNum]").sn_Watermark({waterMarkText: "My Text"} );
      $.sn_Watermark.show("[TextBoxRowNum]");
   });
```

So when I call show it uses the "hard coded" defaults.
I was trying to do something like this, but without any luck.

```
 $.sn_Watermark = $.sn_Watermark || {
        options: {
            waterMarkText: "Watermark Text",
            className: "watermarked"
        },
        show: function(selector) {
            $(selector)
                .addClass(options.waterMarkTest)
                .val(options.className);
        }
    };
```

So my question is, is there an easy way to pass in the options in the show method?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to create an external method to apply these options via extend.

why don't you try to put the options inside the plugin function, and then extend them?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.sn_Watermark = $.sn_Watermark || {
    options: {
        waterMarkText: "Watermark Text",
        className: "watermarked"
    },
    show: function(selector) {
        $(selector)
            .addClass($.sn_Watermark.options.className)
            .val($.sn_Watermark.options.waterMarkText);
    }
};
```

Got it. Have it call it's self.